# how to access an s3 bucket given user name and keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

a friend gave me information on his s3 bucket, so I can look at his logs:

- user name
- access key
- secret key

A lot of the material I have is to access *your own* bucket, but how do people share a particular s3 bucket?

Comment: If you are using his username, access key, and secret key it shouldn't be your bucket's information

Comment: I don't understand the exact question. As Ramhound said, if you have an access key and a secret key, as well as the bucket name, you have everything you need to know in order to completely access it as if it were your own. What are you trying to achieve? There are plenty of tools that allow to connect to S3 shares.

Comment: @slhck I need to download some logs for work.  He gave me his info... I don't know the basis of how to access S3 buckets. The Amazon web site keeps telling me to create my own bucket and the bucket from my boss' info

Answer (score 3):

S3 buckets can be accessed by anyone as long as you know:

- the bucket name
- the access key
- the secret key

There are many tools that allow you to connect to an S3 bucket and up/download files, including:

- [S3 browser](http://s3browser.com/)
- [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.io/)
- [s3fs](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) (CLI)
- [s3cmd](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd) (CLI)
- …

I'm sure a web search for S3 clients will deliver more results.